# Vim replace: change all instances of isnumeric(XXX) to XXX.isnumeric()

Tags: vim

I know how to do simple replace. But how to tell vim to move the XXX outside? Is there a way to extract it, store it, and place it again?

Answer (score 0):

`:%s/isnumeric(\(.\{-}\))/\1.isnumeric()/g`

`(` and `)` don't need escaping in Vim, so the first `(` is literal. The `\(` and `\)` are for grouping, and then you use `\1` to reference.

`.\{-}` is for non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
%s/\(isnumeric\)(\([^)]\+\))/\2.\1
```